# Hide All Controls in a layout

Tags: java, android, layout, controls, visibility

I have a layout with at least 40 controls, including TextView, Spinners .. etc. ..

I need some function to hide all controls.

can be iterated with a control loop in a given layout? Set the visibility to an invisible?

for example something like:

```
For Each ctl AS Control in Layout
      ctl.Setvisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
Next
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be better to hide parent, but if you prefer you can hide only childs

```
for(int index=0,length=ctrl.getChildCount();index<length;++index)
{
   View view = ctrl.getChildAt(index);
   view.setVisibility(View.GONE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Hide the parent layout of all this control